# How to create tar file which contains only file

Tags: java, linux, unix, tar

I have a file in /tmp/a.crt I will have to make a.tgz which contains a.crt not tmp/a.crt. As i am running tar command through java I can't navigate to /tmp and execute `tar -cvf a.tgz a.crt`
If i run `tar -cvf a.tgz /tmp/a.crt` it creates a a.tgz which contains tmp/a.crt .

I tried `tar --exclude='/tmp' -cvf a.tgz /tmp/a.crt`  but while untaring it says

> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format

> tar: Child returned status 1

Is there any way to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Just use `-C`. Consider using a Java compression library to make your application portable.

Comment: @BoristheSpider didn't understand what should be the exact command, could you please elaborate. Manually can we check in linux promot first then from java same thing I can replicate line-- 
 String[] command = new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/tar -cvf " + "a.tgz" + " " + "/tmp/a.crt" };
            CommandResponse cmdResponse = cmdRunner.runCommandWithConsoleOutput(command);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Bash session demonstrating what you want (as I understand it):

```
# first, create test files
$ mkdir tmp
$ touch tmp/a.crt
$ find .
.
./tmp
./tmp/a.crt

# use "-C" to keep the filename out of the archive
$ tar -C tmp -czvf a.tgz a.crt
a.crt

# confirm results
$ tar tf a.tgz 
a.crt
```

As you can see, in the final `a.tgz` file, there is no `tmp/` directory present.

This is generally a bad idea, creating what is sometimes called a "tar bomb" ([link](http://www.linfo.org/tarbomb.html)). But presumably you have a good reason for it (:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a compressed tar file (`.tgz` or `.tar.gz`), you have to use the [option `z`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/Formats.html#gzip). Otherwise you have only an uncompressed tar file (`.tar`). You probably omitted this option during creation.

Comment: thanks ceving I will use this